# Options for Generating Charts from Oracle Queries

Tags: oracle, charts, oracle-apex

Is there a simple (possibly free) way to generate charts (including Pie) out of Oracle SQL queries. Preferably generated as an image file.

I came across Oracle Chart Builder, but it doesn't seem quite what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably start with Google Charts. There's a demo [here](http://www.pythian.com/news/1490/google-charts-for-dba-tablespaces-allocation/) pulling database data into a chart.

One question is where do you want your image file to go.

Option 1. On to the database server.
You can actually call the URL through the UTL_HTTP package, pull down the raw data and store it in the database as a BLOB or write it to a file with UTL_FILE

Option 2. Into a browser client.
This is where you'd need some gateway between the database server and the browser. 10g/11g has an HTTP server embedded in the database which can be used (eg by a product like Apex). The apex listener is another way to get data out in a format that is easily processed.

An intermediate product, like jasperreports, might also be appropriate. It's a more formal 'enterprisey' approach to database reporting.

Or you can go old-school and have [pie-charts in ol' SQL Plus](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/398/pie-charts-in-sql-how-pathetic-can-you-get)

Comment: Google Charts is kind of what I want. It definitely score points for simplicity, the other options like APEX seem rather cumbersome. It would be nice if there was an option with the power and simplicity of Google Charts without the external dependency. (i.e. an exe/dll that I could call, pass in data, and it would spit out a gif/jpeg).

Answer (score 4):

Oracle Application Express (APEX) lets you build web-based applications using PL/SQL.  It has a pretty decent charting engine so you can use that to build a pie chart from the results of a query.  APEX is free and included with recent versions of Oracle though you will have to do some initial setup and configuration.

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently support oracle but if you can move the data to mysql/postgresql/mssql/h2 then this tool would let you generate charts straight from SQL queries: http://www.sqldashboards.com/sqlchart There is a free version, it includes a tiny watermark.

Answer (score 0):

Some Oracle development programs have a built in reporting tool that can generate charts.  For example, TOAD and SQL Developer both have some charting capabilities.  Other than SQL Developer none of those of programs are free, but chances are your company has a license for one of them.

Comment: It's an option, but in my case I want the chart automatically generated with build scripts (without requiring GUI's).